# Request not distributing equally to all the Cluster Member in WebSphere

Tags: http, cluster-computing, websphere-8

I have a Cluster created with 6 cluster members in WAS. Problem is HTTP request is not distributing equally across all the members eventhough the settings are same across all the members. Cluster members 5 and 6 are getting very less requests.

What could be the possible reasons behind this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link for troubleshooting the plugin load balancing](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21449249). The troubleshooting steps in there should help determine what decisions the plugin is making. [Note: I am assuming you are using the IBM WAS HTTP plugin in an IHS or Apache Web server in front of the WAS cluster].

If that didn't help then I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM Support and they can help diagnose and analyze what is going on.